# return conditional not working as expected

Tags: python, unit-testing, conditional-statements, pytest, return-value

I'm have a function that's applying an additional tag to an aws instance based on a dict of tags that are passed in.

Expected behavior: When more than one **TEST_CUSTOMER_ID** is passed in, the function should return '**shared**'.

The current behavior of the unit test function is returning:

**['test_customer_id1', 'test_customer_id2']**

How can I fix this?

## Parent Function

```
def get_account_value(tags, customer_id):
    
    if not tags:
        return customer_id

    tag_value = tags.get("Account")

    return customer_id if not tag_value or tag_value == customer_id else "shared"
```

## Unit Test

```
def test_get_account_value_customer_list():

    TAGS_NO_VALUE = {'foo':'bar'}
    TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_LIST = ["test_customer_id1", "test_customer_id2"]
    
    response = tagging.get_account_value(TAGS_NO_VALUE, TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_LIST)
    
    assert response == "shared"
```

## Unit test Error

```
 AssertionError: assert ['test_client_id1', 'test_client_id2'] == 'shared'
```

Comment: `tag_value` is `None`, so `not tag_value` is True, so it's normal to have `customer_id` returned (because the left-hand side of the `or` is truthy, there's no reason to evaluate the right-hand side at all -- the expression just short-circuits and returns truthy, so it returns the primary clause's value instead of the `else` clause's value). Why do you expect anything different?

Comment: I'm expecting 'shared' to be returned for customer_id, not the two values that were passed in.

Comment: Yes, but **why** do you think that's what it's supposed to return? I just explained why it's not what it _actually_ returns, but to understand where your internal reasoning went wrong, I'd need to know what that internal reasoning was in the first place.

Comment: Why do you have `not tag_value` in the condition?

Comment: Why don't you just do `if(len(customer_id) != 1) return "shared"`

Answer (score 0):

It raises an error because tag_value ist None because you dont give an Account tag. bool(None) = False. So your test will fail.
You have to change you test function to this:

```py
def test_get_account_value_customer_list():
    TAGS_NO_VALUE = {'Account': 'bar'}
    TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_LIST = ["test_customer_id1", "test_customer_id2"]

    response = tagging.get_account_value(TAGS_NO_VALUE, TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_LIST)

    assert response == "shared"
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: `NO_VALUE` clearly means "No _account_ value". It's the case with no account value that they _want_ to test as returning `shared`. The problem is thus that the logic is wrong, not that the test is wrong.

Comment: yes but cour code checks if an account key is given. So it has to be given to avoid an error. The value can be empty.

Comment: Ideally the code should return the value of customer_id and append the key and value to the tags dict if it doesn't exist. If the key and value are already present, it should return the same value. If the key isn't present, but is given two or more values it should return 'shared' a the value.

Answer (score 0):

In your test, `tag_value` is `None` because there is no value with key `'Account'` in `tags`. Therefore, `if not tag_value` returns True. I think this would do the trick:

```
def get_account_value(tags, customer_id):

    if not tags:
        return customer_id

    tag_value = tags.get("Account")
    
    if not tag_value or tag_value == customer_id:
        if len(customer_id) > 1:
            return "shared"
        return customer_id
```

Comment: This works for this unit test, but breaks all of my other ones. :-(